# Copy random data from one workbook and paste it in same row but different columns in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to copy  some random data from workbook and paste it in same rows but different columns in another workbook. i used split function to get the columns that i want to paste. since i am new to vba, don't know the looping and Assign the Range.

```
Sub Slt2()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim b As Variant
Dim txt As Variant
Dim dest_col As String


     FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
      Source_Sheet = InputBox("Enter source sheet name")
        txt = InputBox("Enter the Destination Columns: ")
        dest_col = Split(txt, ",")

        For i = 0 To UBound(dest_col, 1)

       Workbooks("Sourcefile.xlsx").Sheets(Source_Sheet).Range("B21").Copy
       OpenBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("" & dest_col(0) & "5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValue

       Workbooks("Sourcefile.xlsx").Sheets(Source_Sheet).Range("B21").Copy
       OpenBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("" & dest_col(1) & "5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValue

       Next


   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jyothi and welcome to stack overflow. Could I ask you to elaborate a bit more on what this code is currently doing and why this is what you are aiming for please becuase at the moment I'm not quite sure what's wrong.

Comment: Hi, first  from Sourcefile.xlsx it copy the data from  B21 and paste it in "OpenBook"  in certain cell range. where same range but different column for eg: B5, C5, D5... so i inserted a text box to ask those column names and split those answers. loop through those answers in Range("" & dest_col(0) & "5"). And i dont know how to place those range from loop.. am getting syntax error in above syntax. i dont know if above is correct